# Naive way to violate $\mathsf{SCH}$ at $\aleph_\omega$

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

I asked this question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679785/naive-way-to-violate-sch-at-aleph-omega) and got a partial answer. Shamefully I still haven't figured out myself a full answer, so I would like to ask it here. The usual way to get the failure of $\mathsf{SCH}$ at $\aleph_\omega$ is to start with a suitable model with a large cardinal $\kappa$ satisfying $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$, and then force with "Prikry forcing with interleaved collapses".

A more naive approach would be ordinary Prikry forcing *followed* by a (full support) product or iteration of Levy collapses. Is there absolutely zero chance for this to work? I know there are subtleties, e.g., we cannot expect all cardinals above $\kappa$ to be preserved if we start with a large $2^\kappa$, due to Shelah's bound $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$.

To be concrete, say $\kappa$ is a singular strong limit cardinal with cofinality $\omega$ and $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$. Suppose $\kappa_n$ is an increasing sequence of regular cardinals with limit $\kappa$. Does something like $\prod_n\mathrm{Col}(\kappa_n^{++},<\kappa_{n+1})$ necessarily collapse $\kappa^{++}$? It does preserve $\kappa^+$ by usual arguments. If the partial order $(\prod_{n}\kappa_n^{++},<^*)$ has a cofinal subset of size $\kappa^+$ (equivalently a scale of length $\kappa^+$), then $\kappa^{++}$ will be collapsed by a density argument; $f<^*g$ means $\{n\in\omega:f(n)\geq g(n)\}$ is finite. Jech's paper *On the cofinality of countable products of cardinal numbers* contains much information about cofinalities of countable products. In particular, if we are in a Prikry generic extension $V[G]$ using some measure $U$, $j:V\rightarrow M$ is the corresponding elementary embedding, and $(\kappa_n:n<\omega)$ is the Prikry sequence, then the cofinalities of $\prod_n\kappa_n$ and $\prod_n\kappa_n^+$ are respectively $\mathrm{cf}^Vj(\kappa)$ and $\kappa^+$. But I'm not sure how to compute the cofinality of $\prod_{n}\kappa_n^{++}$; it seems to be $\kappa^{++}$ in case $(\kappa^{++})^M=\kappa^{++}$; that would mean the above attempt to show $\kappa^{++}$ is collapsed doesn't work. There is also the question of what if we use some $(\kappa_n:n<\omega)$ that doesn't come from the Prikry generic sequence.

Comment: Where in the literature can I find that $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$ bound? It's fascinating!

Comment: I do not know the original paper but it is written up in Jech's book, chapter 24 (the specific theorem is theorem 24.33).

Comment: Though not an answer, but see [CARDINAL COLLAPSING AND PRODUCT FORCING](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02129.pdf). In particular if $cf(2^\kappa)=\kappa^+,$ then the product always collapses $2^\kappa$ into $\kappa^+.$ A more general result is true, see Theorem 1.2.

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith The result is due to Shelah. The proof is based on Shelah's pcf theory. You may also look at the paper by Abraham and Magidor in the Handbook of Set theory. The title is ``Cardinal Arithmetic''.

Comment: Thank you Hannes Jakob and Mohammad Golshani